# Embedded Font Styling - Embedded Font Styles vs CSS Styling

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I'm hoping to understand what the difference is between embedding fonts in a site like this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Kulturista Medium';
    src: url('fonts/Kulturista Medium.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/Kulturista Medium.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Kulturista Medium.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Kulturista Medium.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Kulturista Semibold';
    src: url('fonts/Kulturista Semibold.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/Kulturista Semibold.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Kulturista Semibold.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Kulturista Semibold.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Kulturista Semibold Italic';
    src: url('fonts/Kulturista Semibold Italic.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/Kulturista Semibold Italic.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Kulturista Semibold Italic.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Kulturista Semibold Italic.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

vs. just loading one single font like this

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Kulturista';
    src: url('fonts/Kulturista.eot');
    src: local('☺'), url('fonts/Kulturista.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/Kulturista.ttf') format('truetype'), url('fonts/Kulturista Medium.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and styling with CSS

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Kulturista', Fallback, sans-serif;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

I imagine there's a benefit, otherwise you wouldn't want to load more resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers read different types of font, so by using them all you can cover all the browsers, being cross-browser

[`TTF and OTF`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=ttf)

They are supported in all modern browsers, except for Internet Explorer, for which they are only partially supported.

[`WOFF`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff)

it is supported by almost all browsers except older versions of Android Browser and older versions of iOS Safari.

[`EOT`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=eot)

is a font file type only supported by Internet Explorer, and works on versions Internet Explorer 8 and above

---

Regarding your main issue, using your 1st example is the best approach since  changing the `font-weight` and `font-style` declarations of each `@font-face` rule to match each font’s properties, and using the same `font-family` name for each rule, we will no longer need to be overly specific in the CSS file.

You can read more [here](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201012/font-face_tip_define_font-weight_and_font-style_to_keep_your_css_simple/)